# Clean Strings in excel

Tags: regex, excel, spreadsheet

I have the following strings:

```
CH0012337421_23.10.2002
CH0012337421_07.11.2002
CH0012337421_18.02.2003
CH0012337421_07.03.2003
CH0012337421_30.04.2003
CH0012337421_12.05.2003
US7750431022_19.05.2003
US7750431022_02.06.2003
```

I would like to remove everything what is inclusive after the `_`.

Any recommendations how to solve that task in excel easily?

I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all your strings contains underscore `_`, use this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("_",A1)-1)
```

[image]